# How to use a component to act as clickable alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

hey I have designed a rectangle using css and it displays a text inside of it , How can I convert this whole component as a means to navigate to some other url (i have tried using the Link from reactrouterDOM but it changed the shape and also an underline appeared just below the text, which defeated the whole point of it not looking like a link text ).

Any Approach Would be helpful as I am quite new to React.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Link from react-router:

```
<Link to="/url" style={{
    textDecoration: 'none',
    color: 'inherit',
    display: 'inline-block',
}}>
    <Rectangle/>
</Link>
```

If you just want to handle `onClick` in rectangle:

```
export const Rectangle = (props) => (
    <div onClick={props.onClick}>whatever</div>
);
```

and then use it as:

```
<Rectangle onClick={() => console.log('whatever')}/>
```

PS: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Hey the First approach worked perfectly but i think the text content is a bit too long so instead of showing it on a single line, its showing it on 2 lines(even though it contains 2 words), Can you help me with this?Thanks a lot for answering

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;`